# Scraping many pages using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape multiple webpages using scrapy. The link of the pages are like:

```
http://www.example.com/id=some-number
```

In the next page the number at the end is reduced by **1**.

So I am trying to build a spider which navigates to the other pages and scrapes them too. The code that I have is given below:

```
import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.http import Request

URL = "http://www.example.com/id=%d"
starting_number = 1000
number_of_pages = 500
class FinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [URL % starting_number]

    def start_request(self):
        for i in range (starting_number, number_of_pages, -1):
            yield Request(url = URL % i, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        **parsing data from the webpage**
```

This is running into an infinite loop where on printing the page number I am getting negative numbers. I think that is happening because I am requesting for a page within my `parse()` function.

But then the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897669/scraping-multiple-pages-with-scrapy) works okay. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first page requested is "http://www.example.com/id=1000" (`starting_number`)

It's response goes through `parse()` and with `for i in range (0, 500):`
 you are requesting `http://www.example.com/id=999`, `http://www.example.com/id=998`, `http://www.example.com/id=997`...`http://www.example.com/id=500`

`self.page_number` is a spider attribute, so when you're decrementing it's value, you have `self.page_number == 500` after the first `parse()`.

So when Scrapy calls `parse` for the response of `http://www.example.com/id=999`, you're generating requests for `http://www.example.com/id=499`, `http://www.example.com/id=498`, `http://www.example.com/id=497`...`http://www.example.com/id=0`

You guess what happens the 3rd time: `http://www.example.com/id=-1`, `http://www.example.com/id=-2`...`http://www.example.com/id=-500`

For each response, you're generating 500 requests.

You can stop the loop by testing `self.page_number >= 0`

---

Edit after OP question in comments:

No need for multiple threads, Scrapy works asynchronously and you can enqueue all your requests in an overridden `start_requests()` method (instead of requesting 1 page, and then returning `Request` istances in the `parse` method).
Scrapy will take enough requests to fill it's pipeline, parse the pages, pick new requests to send and so on.

See [start_requests documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests).

Something like this would work:

```
class FinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [URL % starting_number]
    def __init__(self):
        self.page_number = starting_number

    def start_requests(self):
        # generate page IDs from 1000 down to 501
        for i in range (self.page_number, number_of_pages, -1):
            yield Request(url = URL % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        **parsing data from the webpage**
```

Comment: Your method works perfectly. Is there any other way that I can do this, run multiple threads maybe? Something on those lines?

Comment: Its not working. Its scraping the first page and then quitting. I'll edit the code of the spider to illustrate.

Comment: What does "This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl for this spider." mean exactly? I think that might be the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You wrote 'start_request' instead of 'start_requests'