# Scrapy: scraping a list of links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This question is somewhat a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779889/scraping-many-pages-using-scrapy) question that I asked previously.

I am trying to scrape a website which contains some links on the first page. Something similar to [this](http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=phones&as=off&as-show=on&otracker=start).

Now, since I want to scrape the details of the items present on the page I have extracted their individual URLs.

I have saved these URLS in a list.

How do I launch spiders to scrape the pages individually?

For better understanding:

```
[urlA, urlB, urlC, urlD...]
```

This is the list of URLs that I have scraped. Now I want to launch a spider to scrape the links individually.

How do I go about this?

Comment: I think you should re-read the answer in your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779889/scraping-many-pages-using-scrapy). You don't generate a list of URLs, you return a list of new Request objects from start_request for those URLs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the urls you want to follow lead to pages with the same or similar structure. If that's the case, you should do something like this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):

   name = 'yourCrawler'
   allowed_domains = 'domain.com'
   start_urls = ["htttp://www.domain.com/example/url"]


   def parse(self, response):
      #parse any elements you need from the start_urls and, optionally, store them as Items.
      # See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

      s = Selector(response)
      urls = s.xpath('//div[@id="example"]//a/@href').extract()
      for url in urls:
         yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)


   def parse_following_urls(self, response):
       #Parsing rules go here
```

Otherwise, if urls you want to follow lead to pages with different structure, then you can define specific methods for them (something like parse1, parse2, parse3...).