# Scrapy: AttributeError: 'YourCrawler' object has no attribute 'parse_following_urls'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider. I have been reading this question: [Scrapy: scraping a list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984064/scrapy-scraping-a-list-of-links), and I can make it recognise the urls in a listpage, but I cant make it go inside the urls and save the data I want to see.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bookstore_2"
    start_urls = [
    'https://example.com/materias/?novedades=LC&p',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # go to the urls in the list
        s = Selector(response)
        page_list_urls = s.xpath('///*[@id="results"]/ul/li/div[1]/h4/a[2]/@href').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)

            # For the urls in the list, go inside, and in div#main, take the div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li
            def parse_following_urls(self, response):
                #Parsing rules go here
                for each_book in response.css('div#main'):
                    yield {
                    'book_isbn': each_book.css('div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li').extract(),
                    }
                    # Return back and go to bext page in div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href) and begin again
                    next_page = response.css('div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                    if next_page is not None:
                        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

It gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'YourCrawler' object has no attribute 'parse_following_urls'
```

And I don't understand why!

EDIT --

As the response says, I had to close the method with the indentation like here:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bookstore_2"
    start_urls = [
    'https://example.com/materias/?novedades=LC&p',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # go to the urls in the list
        s = Selector(response)
        page_list_urls = s.xpath('///*[@id="results"]/ul/li/div[1]/h4/a[2]/@href').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)

    # For the urls in the list, go inside, and in div#main, take the div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li
    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        #Parsing rules go here
        for each_book in response.css('div#main'):
            yield {
            'book_isbn': each_book.css('div.ficha > div.caracteristicas > ul > li').extract(),
            }
            # Return back and go to bext page in div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href) and begin again
            next_page = response.css('div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

But there is another problem, I think related to the urls, and now I am having this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/nikita/scrapy/bookstore_2/bookstore_2/spiders/bookstore_2.py", line 16, in parse
    yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 58, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /book/?id=9780374281083
```

Maybe because I have to tell scrappy what is the base url? Should I add somewhere a urljoin?

EDIT_2 ---

Ok, the problem was with the urls. Adding

```
response.urljoin(
```

solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
  yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)
```

you used parse_following_urls with self.
But parse_following_urls is defined in parse function, so it isn't a method of YourCrawler.
That's why the error said 
`AttributeError: 'YourCrawler' object has no attribute 'parse_following_urls'`
you should assign it like:

```
class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
    ....
```

to make it method of the class.

### edit

for a additional question:
In your code `s.xpath('///*[@id="results"]/ul/li/div[1]/h4/a[2]/@href')` indicates the href attribute of the element a tag of the html page you want to scrap.
 However, it is only '/book/?id=9780374281083', not the full url.
 so, you should make it like : `https://lacentral.com/book/?id=9780374281083`
 to use it.

Comment: A small clarification: you don't have to move the method to the beginning of the class declaration. The important thing is that methods cannot be nested inside other methods.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand where has to go the `def parse_following_urls(self, response):` part. I have put this out of the method, is this correct? I though I was following the response in [Scrapy: scraping a list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984064/scrapy-scraping-a-list-of-links)!
Maybe is a problem with the indentation?

Comment: In your code, the parse_following_urls part is nested in parse function part. you have to put that out as you mentioned. The answer from your link is not nested too. the parse function and parse_following_urls function has same indentation level.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize about indentation in Python until now… I have another error related to urls, I'll update the question! :)

Comment: About the additional question, what about using `yield Request(response.urljoin(url),` instead of `yield Request(url,`?

Comment: Yeah, this works, it add the base url as @park suggested, but now it doesn't want to go to the next page ¿?

Comment: I will open a new question about the issue with the next page.