# Scrape using Scrapy using Urls taken from a list

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class PractiseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "practise"
    allowed_domains = ["practise.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://practise.com/product/{}/']
    def parse(self, response):
        #do something
        #scrape with next url in the list
```

My list `m` contains the url needed to be added like `product/{}/.format(m[i])`
iteratively.
How do I do this. Should I make new spider calls for each Url  or should I write some code for the spider to automatically iterate the list. If the answer is the latter what do i write ?

I know there are many answers related to this, for e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984064/scrapy-scraping-a-list-of-links?rq=1) but i have a fixed and known list of urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the URLs beforehand, just populate `start_urls`. If you say `m` is a list of products (that's what I assume from what you wrote), then it would look like this:

```
start_urls = ['https://practise.com/product/{}/'.format(product) for product in m]
```

Comment: @twitu You don't need to, that's handled by Scrapy for you - it will scrape all the URLs from `start_urls` and call your `parse` method with the response.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to overriding `start_urls`, you can override `start_requests()` method of your spider. This method yields requests that start off your spider.

By default your spider does this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```

so you can modify this method in your spider to anything you want to:

```
def start_requests(self):
    ids = pop_ids_from_db()
    for id in ids:
        url = f'http://example.com/product/{id}'
        yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```